# Restricting copy,paste option for a particular UITextfield

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, copy-paste

My UIView contains Two UITextField.I need to restrict copy,paste option for one textfield.I don't want to restrict that for another.

When i am using the following code,Both the field gets restricted from copy,paste.

```
-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender 
{
    if ( [UIMenuController sharedMenuController] )
    {
            [UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuVisible = NO;
    }
     return NO;
}
```

Can any one provide me the solution to solve my problem.

Comment: Have you tried setting `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO`? Or should the UITextView still be editable?

Comment: @afEken I think it should be editable

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Create a subclass of UITextField. In that subclass, implement

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    if (sel_isEqual(action, @selector(copy:))) {
        return NO;
    }
    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

Then use this subclass for the field that you don't want to be able to copy in, and use a regular UITextField for the one that you can copy from.

Comment: Its fine...But I don't want to display any Menu(Cut,Copy,paste,select,etc.,) for the restricted UITextfield.

Comment: You can try your `[UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuVisible` thing inside of `-canPerformAction:` in that case. As long as you only do it from within your subclass, it should behave as expected.

Comment: Could you just always return NO to disable all actions?

Comment: @kevboh I see no reason why you can't.

Comment: Well then there you go, no menu = return NO.

Comment: I tried this and got a message about del_isEqual not being allowed in C99 so I just used (action == @selector(copy:)) and it seems to be working.

Comment: @MarkLeonard: You may have to `#import <objc/runtime.h>` to get access to `sel_isEqual()`.

Comment: @KevinBallard What should i do if i've added `UITextField` in `UITableView` for only single `UITextField`.

Answer (score 4):

The following prevents any string longer than 1 character to be pasted. String that is 1 character long will however get through (could be useful to some people - doesn't need subclassing).

First give your textField a delegate

```
myTextField.delegate = self; // OR [myTextField setDelegate:self];
```

Then add the following method to your ViewController

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

    if ( [string length] > 1) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: @cbdhac : Thanks for your answer.But the thing is I don't want to paste single char too .

Comment: This code won't prevent strings with more than 1 character going through, it will prevent strings with more than 1 byte going through... so this will prevent the user from typing unicode characters with more than 1 byte as well (like EMOJI characters).

Answer (score 2):

Explanantion from Apple:

> This default implementation of this
>   method returns YES if the responder
>   class implements the requested action
>   and calls the next responder if it
>   does not. Subclasses may override this
>   method to enable menu commands based
>   on the current state; for example, you
>   would enable the Copy command if there
>   is a selection or disable the Paste
>   command if the pasteboard did not
>   contain data with the correct
>   pasteboard representation type.

So, the solution is to subclass the UITextView and return properly.

[More information about the method here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/canPerformAction%3awithSender%3a)

Answer (score 1):

I had a random idea that worked perfectly on a text view. No reason why it wouldn't work on a text field.

I added the following to the text field I wanted to restrict.

- Long Press Gesture Recognizer (1 touch)
- Long Press Gesture Recognizer (2 touches)
- Tap Gesture Recognizer (2 taps, 1 touch)
- Tap Gesture Recognizer (3 taps, 1 touch)
- Tap Gesture Recognizer (1 tap, 2 touches)

Then assigned the following code to it.

```
- (IBAction)cancelTouch:(id)sender {
    //do nothing
}
```

I can now still scroll through the textview but a long press or double tap now do absolutely nothing!